# what is the difference between reactLocalStorage and localStorage?

Tags: reactjs

I found **reactLocalStorage** and **localStorage** does the same: stores data in browser's local storage. Only the differences are the method names: **reactLocalStorage.get(key)**, **localStorage.getItem(key)** ... So, what is the importance of using reactLocalStorage? Is there any performance issue?

NB: Both reactLocalStorage and localStorage work with react.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `reactLocalStorage`? Is it a library?

Comment: ``reactLocalStorage`` does not exist

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage

Comment: You can look through the code and see everything that package does [here](https://github.com/null-none/react-localstorage/blob/master/react-localstorage.js) (basically it just does the encoding/decoding of objects for you when you want to store an object)

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot.